# NPE when running arquillian against remote Wildfly-8.0.0

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

Yesterday, when trying to move my integration tests from **embedded GF 4** to the **remote Wildfly 8** I was getting strange `NullPointerException` for every arquillian test run against remote Wildfly 8 instance. The same integration test worked just fine on embedded Glassfish 4.0.

```
org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.DeploymentException: Cannot deploy: test.war
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.deployInternal(ArchiveDeployer.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.deployInternal(ArchiveDeployer.java:64)
    at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.deploy(ArchiveDeployer.java:46)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"test.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"}}
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.getActionResult(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:134)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.getResultFromNode(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:123)
```

My test case was extremely easy (deployment with single class), not need to post here.
Components used:

- Arquillian 1.1.5.Final
- Wildfly 8.0.0.Final
- Eclipse Luna

No matter what was the way to launch my test case (from Eclipse IDE and with `mvn integration-test`) result was the same.

I've lost whole day but managed to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've managed to fix above error by starting the same server from the command line (not from Eclipse IDE):

```
wildfly-8.0.0.Final\bin\standalone.bat
```

Suddenly problem was gone. Now my integration tests works fine against remote Wildfly.
Also I've noticed that original problem doesn't occur anymore on `wildfly 8.1.0`.

Hope it will help somebody.